# Delete "Desi" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-blacklist-request

There is a tag [desi](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desi) that doesn't appear to have any meaning, it's probably just a typo of [design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design). Since we already have a design tag can we get this one deleted?

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desi

Comment: Desi in India means "local".  Like, desi boy or desi style etc etc. I was bit surprised(shocked) to know about this tag. Good that its gone :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's gone now, but it'll take some time to disappear. Like a windows timer job...

## Edited 19 hours later

Now it's permanently deleted :-)